# How to build an effective card collection on Magic Online?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-online

I just started playing Magic: The Gathering Online and was wondering what the best way to go about building a collection focused on being able to play and compete in multiple formats with the only limitations being my own skill.

Is it better to focus on drafting and building up a collection that way or is there a better way to acquire cards?

Comment: Cardhoarder has a nice page related to this [here](https://cardhoarder.com/mtgo-beginner-guide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way to build up a collection is to buy cheap cards from the bots. They'll sell junk commons for around 128/tix.

However, the *vast majority* of competitive tournaments/games that you'll be playing in are going to be a limited format, meaning that you only have the cards you open during the game (such as in drafting which you mention). Pre-constructed tournaments are quite rare in Magic Online; and so your collection will not have much input onto your games.

That's not to say that having a large collection and good knowledge of the current sets isn't important in the limited formats (it is!), just that the size of your collection itself doesn't mean much in the competitive arena.

Comment: And if you *are* exclusively going to play constructed, for whatever reason, you'll probably find it easiest to do exactly what you do in real life, that is buy or trade for the singles you need.   If you play a lot of drafts trying to a get a playset of a rare you need you're gonna have a bad time.